# Multiple IP adresses for a single SSL certificate, no DNS server

Tags: ssl, certificate

I want to setup the following configuration: a single SSL certificate tied with multiple ip adresses to ensure a secured https connection with the rest of the LAN. Is it possible considering the fact that I don't have a DNS server installed (so I cannot use FQDM)?

Answer (score 8):

Yes.  Certificates can have IP addresses in their Subject Alternative Name extensions. You haven't said what you're using to create the certificate requests, but if you're using OpenSSL, you'll need something like the following in your configuration file:

```
req_extensions = req_ext

[ req_ext ]

subjectAltName = @alt_names

[alt_names]
IP.1 = 192.168.0.10
IP.2 = 192.168.0.11
```